# How to create several settings files?

Tags: xml, wpf, .net-4.0, application-settings

I need to separate data from user settings into several files because some settings are too large and already are in XML (e.g. `AvalonDock` layout).

But I am not able to find suitable solutions. If I use `SettingsSingleFileGenerator`, 
I can't separate settings. But also I can't get the path of the file `user.config` - the property `UserAppDataPath` exists only in `WinForms` application class but I use `WPF`. Environment folders don't match the settings path, the nearest one is `LocalApplicationData` but `subdirectories` in fact don't match any of entry assembly attribute (it isn't always `CompanyName\ProductName\ProductVersion`, but often with some random hash).

What is the best way to save raw XML settings in a separate file in the same directory?

The SettingsSingleFileGenerator source is like this code:

```
xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings"; 
CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="STOProcedures.Warehouse.Properties"
GeneratedClassName="Settings"> 
<Profiles /> 
 <Settings> 
   <Setting Name="MultipleActionMode" Type="System.String" Scope="User"> 
       <Value Profile="(Default)">Fade</Value> 
    </Setting>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.. First of all have u tried anything???

Comment: I think I've described what i've tried - i've not succeded to find some SettingsSingleFileGenerator configuration that can separate settings into several files. Next I've not succeded to get the settings path directly (it was, as I've noted, with a random hash). I have no more ideas myself and I've not found proper information over the Web...

Comment: Please put code whatever u have tried so far..

Comment: The SettingsSingleFileGenerator source is like this `code` SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="STOProcedures.Warehouse.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings"> <Profiles /> <Settings> <Setting Name="MultipleActionMode" Type="System.String" Scope="User"> <Value Profile="(Default)">Fade</Value> </Setting> `code`
The code I've tried to get the settings path is

Comment: That code is `code`string settingsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);`code` The line I could find over the Web that is `code`string settingsPath = Application.UserAppDataPath; `code` will not compile 'cause it isn't WinForms.

Comment: Please put that code yourself by editing your question